# Want to Refresh the page when i click the browser back button

Tags: php, html, browser, refresh, back

I'm making a website in which there is a login page and then the home page..
Now once I have logged in I want this to happen.

It should not go back to the login page when I click THE BROWSER BACK BUTTON.

It should refresh the home page jus like HOW FACEBOOK DOES..

I have checked and googled but I am not finding the answer...

I would really appreciate it if anyone helps me...
Thank You..

This is the **login page.**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>mindclik</TITLE>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets\home.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/home.css">
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<div id="wrap">
<div id="main">
<div id ="left">
</br>
<h2>Login</h2>
<form id="login_form" action="home.php" method="post" >
<table >
<tr>
<td>
Email:
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="login_tb" >
</td>   
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
Password:
</td>
<td>
<input type=password name="pwd" id="pwd"" class="login_tb"> 
</td>   
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
</td>
<td>
<input type=submit id="sub" value="SignIn">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form></div>
</div></div>
```

This is the **homePage.php**

```
<?php 

$p_uname=$_POST['email'];
$p_pass=$_POST['pwd'];
$enc_pass=md5($p_pass);
?>   
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/home1.css">

</head>
<body>


<div id="wrap">

<div id="left_contain"> Friend List</div>
<div id="main"></div>
<div id="right_contain_top">Friend New Answers</div>
<div id="right_contain_bot">Questions From AOF</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tagging this for the languages you are using would be helpful

Comment: have you tried `<body onload="document.refresh();">  ` or perhaps `document.location.reload(true);` yet??

Comment: @luchosrock where should i put that code... in the login page or the Home page

Comment: in the page you want to always refresh

Comment: @luchosrock I tried but not working....

Comment: @user2524115 You need what `Sudeep` posted below, as well as **sessions**. Using only cookies is not good enough, because cookies can always be deleted from the user's computer. You can read more about sessions by going to the following link: http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Comment: @Fred Where should I start the session???  I know a bit of sessions... Thanks for all the help..

Comment: @user2524115 First you need to have `session_start();` inside every PHP file that will be used, located at the top, underneath your opening PHP tag `<?php`.

Comment: I seriously hope you've solved this by now, but... See the linked duplicate if you haven't.

Answer (score 0):

You can set cookies once the user is authenticated. On successful login

```
 setcookie("Valid", $user_name);
```

In the login page place this at the top.

```
<?php
 if ($_COOKIE['Valid'] == $user_name ) {
    header( 'Location: homepage.php' ) ;
 }
?>
```

This hack would work. Change the file extension of login page to .php

Comment: not Working... it is still going back to the login page..